# Regarding possible edges in a graph: Do they lie on a gauss curve?

Tags: graph-theory

I've written a program to find out the number of possible isomorphic graphs in a set of $V$ vertices and graphed the output. Unfortunately my program would not go beyond $7$ vertices because the factorials became too big.

It looks like the distribution of possible graphs with $1 \dots n$ edges in a set of $V$ vertices with $\dfrac{(V(V-1))}{2}$ *possible* edges follows a gauss curve. Is there a way to describe this curve in terms of $V$?

And do the peaks of those curves lie on a function that can be expressed in terms of $V$?

Comment: A non-mathematical (but programming related) note: Some languages like C, C++, Fortran are restricted to fixed size _types_ which prevents you from evaluating large integers easily. Other languages like Python for example, have variable length types for integers. On my computer it only takes a few seconds to evaluate $(10^5)!$, a number with about half a million digits.

Comment: @Hooked ... but testing the $(10^5)!$ possible vertex permutations if they are or are not a graph isomorphism among two out of $2^{10^{10}/2}$ graphs *might* take a bit longer.

Comment: Note that two graphs with $k$ edges are isomorphic iff the complementary graphs with $\frac{V(V-1)}{2}-k$ edges are isomorphic. Hence the isomorphism class counts are surely symmetric around $\frac{V(V-1)}{4}$.

Comment: The number of $k$-subsets of the potential edge set is $\frac{V(V-1)}{2}\choose k$, so that follows a good approximation of a Gauß curve. One may argue that for $V$ big and $k$ close to the middle, the "probability" of two random graphs being isomorphic is very small, so that binomial coefficient is alrady a good approximation for the (relative) isomorphsm class count.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen No argument here! This is why I prefixed my comment that it was a programming observation only. It comes down to how the statement was interpreted. OP noted that "Unfortunately my program would not go beyond 7... because the factorials became too big". I simply noted that if the problem was the machine representation of the the number there are alternatives. If however, you read OP's statement that the number of combinations were too large to check by brute force than I completely agree!

Answer (score 3):

The number of non-isomoprhic $n$-vertex $q$-edge graphs is $$\frac{1}{n!} \sum_G |\mathrm{aut}(G)|$$ where the sum is over all $n$-vertex $q$-edge labelled graphs $G$, and $\mathrm{aut}(G)$ denotes the automorphism group of $G$.  This equals $$\frac{\nu}{n!} \binom{\binom{n}{2}}{q}$$ where $\nu$ is the expected size of the automorphism group of a $n$-vertex $q$-edge labelled graph chosen uniformly at random.

From Wright (1974): if $\mu := (2q-n\log n)/n$ and $q \leq \frac{1}{2} \binom{n}{2}$ and $\mu \rightarrow \infty$, then almost all $n$-vertex $q$-edge graphs are asymmetric; i.e. $\nu=1$.  So we have an asymptotically Gaussian-like distribution where the above condition is satisfied (noting that the distribution is symmetric about $\frac{1}{2} \binom{n}{2}$).

> Wright, E. M. [Asymmetric and symmetric graphs](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0017089500002159). Glasgow Math. J. 15 (1974), 69–73.

---

For 10-vertex graphs, the data looks like:

[image: 10-vertex graphs]

where the "predicted" value is $\frac{1}{n!} \binom{\binom{n}{2}}{q}$.  These numbers can be readily computed using `geng` which comes with [nauty](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/).